# BeautifulSoup AttributeError: NoneType object has no attribute find

Tags: python-2.7, beautifulsoup

I am using BeuatifulSoup in Python to extract the total count of the number of test cases from the report and I am getting the error:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find'
```

Full error trace:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/test_runners 2 edit project/selenium_regression_test_5_1_1/Email/email_selenium_report_for_edit_project_test.py", line 32, in <module>
    report_for_edit_project_test.send_report_summary_from_htmltestrunner_selenium_grouping_edit_project_report("IE10")
  File "C:\test_runners 2 edit project\selenium_regression_test_5_1_1\Email\report_for_edit_project_test.py", line 567, in send_report_summary_from_htmltestrunner_selenium_grouping_edit_project_report
    text.append(extract_total_from_grouping_report_htmltestrunner(browser_version))
  File "C:\test_runners 2 edit project\selenium_regression_test_5_1_1\Email\report_for_edit_project_test.py", line 132, in extract_total_from_grouping_report_htmltestrunner
    tr_total_row.find('td')
```

My method implementation is:

```
def extract_total_from_grouping_report_htmltestrunner(
    browser_version):  # Extract the total count of the number of test cases from the report e.g 93 test cases
# Params browser_version : e.g. IE11, IE10
# filename = (
# r"E:\test_runners 2 edit project\selenium_regression_test_5_1_1\TestReport\ClearCore501_Automated_GUI_Regression_EditProject_Grouping_" + browser_version + "_TestReport.html")
if browser_version == "IE11":
    filename = Globals.test_report_for_grouping_edit_project_filepath_IE11
elif browser_version == "IE10":
    filename = Globals.test_report_for_grouping_edit_project_filepath_IE10
html_report_part = open(filename, 'r')
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_report_part, "html.parser")
tr_total_row = soup.find('tr', {'id': 'total_row'})
# tr_total = tr_total_row.find('strong', text='Status:').parent
# tr_total_row.find(text=True, recursive=False)
tr_total_row.find('td')
col = tr_total_row.find_all('td')
total_column_0 = col[0].string.strip()
count_column_1 = col[1].string.strip()

# print tr_total_row.text
#    print total_column_0
#    print count_column_1
total_testcase_count = total_column_0.join("   ").join(count_column_1)

total_items = []
total_items.append(total_column_0)
total_items.append("")
total_items.append(" TestCases = ")
total_items.append(count_column_1)
str = "".join(total_items)
# str = "\n".join(total_items)
print str

# return tr_total_row.text
# return total_testcase_count
return str
```

I am not sure why it is complaining, the line the error is on is tr_total_row.find('td')

The HTML sample from the Report is:

```
<table id='result_table'>
    tr id='total_row'>
    <td>Total</td>
    <td>67</td>
    <td>66</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Some help please.  Thanks, regards, Riaz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The HTML Syntax is invalid. When I tried your html and printed `soup`, The syntax error was starring at me.

```
>>> soup
<body>\n<table id="result_table">\n    tr id='total_row'&gt;\n    <td>Total</td>\n<td>67</td>\n<td>66</td>\n<td>0</td>\n<td>1</td>\n<td>\xa0</td>\n</table></body>\n\n\n
```

**tr id='total_row'>**

After fixing the syntax:

```
>>> soup
<body>\n<table id="result_table">\n<tr id="total_row">\n<td>Total</td>\n<td>67</td>\n<td>66</td>\n<td>0</td>\n<td>1</td>\n<td>\xa0</td>\n</tr>\n</table>\n</body>\n
```

The script returned:

> Total TestCases = 67